# Landscape mode resizing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Im developing an application to display a gallery of images by using a UIScrollView, the sliding between images works fine on portrait mode but when changed to landscape mode it shows the image plus a portion of the next image.
If i could get some explanation on how to solve this issue i would be very thankful.

Comment: You need to adjust widths and heights and spacing among thumbnails dynamically. This is the general concept, but as @sergio said, if you need more help, you need to post some codes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your UIScrollView and it's parent view have the right `UIViewAutoResizing` and `autoResizesSubViews` values.

Then listen for device orientation changes and take appropriate steps (= reposition subviews of the scrollview)

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   // ... other things

   [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
};

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {   
     UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

   if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
       NSLog(@"Landscape Left!");
   }
}
```